# Restrict only Ipad 1 in appstore

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, app-store

I need to restrict my IOS app in only IPAD 1. Other IPADs are ok. It supports IPHONE 4 and above too.

Is there a way?

Comment: I was thinking of restricting by blocking IOS 5.1.1 and below but that is not an option now.

Comment: set Deployment target for ios 6.'

Comment: virus. thats the problem mate.i ve got to support ios5 devices too.

Comment: You can not Restrict particular one item. you can do is create two app   one for iPhone and i for iPad, in iPad set your dep. target to 6. and in iphone version set it to 5.0 .

Comment: no go for that too mate. its a single app that supports both iphone and ipad at the same time. splitting it ll be too much pain.

Comment: was thinking in the line of some hardware restriction. is there a chart to reference?

Comment: What is it about the original iPad that doesn't work with your app?  (Maybe that would point to something you could require.)

Comment: Philip the app needs more ram.

Comment: You might have to (ugly) check for the device and then refuse to run on iPad 1. If this is a free app then it's just irritating to the extremely few who still have 1's. If it costs money then this wouldn't work. In that case you can't have a universal app. The number of people who still use 5.X is pretty limited, less than 1% on an iPhone app we have that still supports 5.X.

Comment: What kind of app is it? If you are using too much RAM that is never a good sign ;). Use Instruments to find out where your app needs so much memory. There are nearly always ways to reduce the memory footprint (that could require a quite large refactoring) - if you don't have the time/money for that you should try to make as many parts of the app as possible running on iPad 1 and disable some functionality.

Comment: HAS - its a game. so i guess its normal.

Comment: ahwulf - cant do that. One or two negative ratings is still a thorn for us. we just released it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see here:

[App-Related Resources](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW10)

under the **Declaring the Required Device Capabilities** section, you can declare **UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities** in your Info.plist file. It means that you declare hardware that your app requires in order to run. The App Store uses the contents of this key to prevent users from downloading your app onto a device that cannot possibly run it.

In your case, I think you can require the **front-facing-camera** to exclude the iPad 1gen.

Another way is to set the development target to iOS 6.0 which is not supported on the iPad 1.

Comment: nice one mate. this ll do.

Comment: That link also says, "You should include keys only for the features that your app absolutely requires. If your app can run without a specific feature, do not include the corresponding key."  I don't know whether reviewers check for that but you should be aware of the point.

Comment: Can this be changed in an already published app? What could happen?